# How to define function for a dom object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a part of a more [broad question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635376/master-detail-pattern-for-html-page-with-jquery). It is getting low attention, so let me please  ask the only part of it that I can't implement myself. How can I register jquery-like javascript function for a dom object? Say i have a following html page:

```
<html><body>
  <div id = "table"/>
  <div id = "chart"/>
</body></html>
```

and want to be able to call `$('#table').update()` and `$('#chart').update()`? I need those update functions to contain different logic and local variables, for example different url to load data from. Sorry for probably being noob.

**UPDATE**

If I understand correctly,  plugin is a function in a global namespace that can process any object. I'd rather want to associate different functions with different elements. That because I thought that it would be easier to associate different `update` functions with different objects, than write one update function which for every object has to investigate is it applicable, and if yes, how.

Comment: Is `update()` a plugin you've written? You could use `data-*` variables on the elements containing the differing data, and process the logic on them in your `update()` method.

Comment: Are you asking how to [create a plugin](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)?

Comment: I do not know whether plugin is a solution, and updated my question accordingly

Comment: "jquery-like javascript function for a dom object" You are not calling DOM object methods, but jQuery functions in your example: `$('#table').update()`. To call a DOM object method you will need to access the DOM object first: `$('#table')[0].update()` or `$('#table').item(0).update()`. See: http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery jQuery plugin functions can be created/appended using the  `extend` function as @James Donnelly suggests; to add a DOM method you must set it to the objects prototype.

Comment: thanks @feela I think your comment is worth being an answer, it clarified me why some of my attempts failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this. DOM elements are objects, so you can give them any methods you want:

```
var table = document.getElementById('table');
table.update = function() {
  this.innerHTML += 'table updated ';
}.bind(table);

var chart = document.getElementById('chart');
chart.update = function() {
  this.innerHTML += 'chart updated ';
}.bind(chart);


document.getElementById('table').update();
document.querySelector('#chart').update();
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/uReyIRi/1/edit

Comment: seems that this `.bind` thing is what i missed!

Comment: "this bind thing" is used to make sure the function runs in the context of the object it was defined on. Glad to be of help. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 6):

What you're after is [jQuery's `fn.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fn.extend/):

```
$.fn.extend({
    update: function() {
        /* Required code. */
    }
});
```

Then you can simply call `.update()` on a jQuery object to execute that function:

```
$('myElement').update();
```

---

As an example use, if we wanted to log the `id` of an element, we could define our `update()` function as:

```
$.fn.extend({
    update: function() {
        console.log("ID = " + this.id);
    }
});
```

Then call:

```
$('#table').update();
```

Which would log:

> ID = table

Comment: Small typo in you answer; upload should be update ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can add new methods to the DOM objects via their prototypes.

```
/* extend existing prototype */
HTMLTable.prototype.update = function() {
    console.log( this );
}

/* call new method */
document.querySelector( 'table' ).update();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype